# Refactor if conditional blocks with multiple returns

Tags: java, if-statement

In one of the applications, had to execute tasks in a sequential manner. There are 'n' number of tasks and they need to be executed if the previous task is completed successfully - tracked by the status variable.

The multiple if conditions in the method looks ugly and need to be replaced by some sort.

```
public boolean process() {
  String status;
  status = doTask1();
  if (StringUtils.equals(status, "error")) {
    return true;
  }
  status = doTask2();
  if (StringUtils.equals(status, "error")) {
      return true;
  }
  status = doTask3();
  if (StringUtils.equals(status, "error")) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid continuous "if (...)" checks while executing function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67899326/avoid-continuous-if-checks-while-executing-function)

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a list of tasks then iterate over them.

```
private final List<Supplier<String>> tasks = Arrays.asList(
    this::doTask1, this::doTask2, this::doTask3
);

public boolean process() {
    for (Supplier<String> task : tasks) {
        if (task.get().equals("error")) {
            return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
public enum Status {
    ERROR, TASK_1, ... TASK_N, END;
}

public boolean process() {
    Status status = TASK_1;
    while(status != ERROR && status != END) {
        switch(status) {
        case TASK_1: status = doTask1(); break;
        .....
        case TASK_N: status = doTaskN(); break;
    }
    return (status == ERROR);
}
```

Ultimately, maybe what you need is a `Task` class with a `do()` method, and each `do()` returns a new `Task` object. But that could be considered over-engineering.

Also, look up the term "Finite State Machine"

Comment: I think that the doTask is not always the same function with a different parameter

Comment: I suppose `doTask` ends up being a giant switch statement, right? And it's theoretically possible to pass `doTask` a status of ERROR which does not represent a task, so it has to either throw an exception or just ignore the error.

Comment: @Michael Fair point. Let me bring the switch statement into this method

Answer (score 1):

Simple `return` statement can also be used in this case as:

```java
return doTask1().equals("error") || doTask2().equals("error") || doTaskN().equals("error");
```